# \Dotfill Not Completely Filling Dots

Tags: table-of-contents, leaders

I am typesetting a book and am using `\dotfill` to produce a sequence of dots extending to the displayed page number in the Table of Contents.

Alas, with the following (MWE) code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{\textbf{TRANSLATOR'S PREFACE}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Translator's Preface \dotfill}}

\newpage

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

I produce the following output:

[image]

Can somebody help me to remedy this so that the dots extend all the way to the page number as usual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) already inserts a *leader* as part of setting a chapter in the ToC; it's just a blank leader (or `\hfill`). And, butting these leaders together (a `\dotfill` and `\hfill`) just makes them share the distance between the end points. That's why your leader - `\dotfill` - goes only half-way.

Remedy this by specifying the appropriate `chapter` leader using `tocloft`'s style:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\dotfill}
```

Remember to remove the `\dotfill` from your `\addcontentsline` insertion.

If you want it **bold** you can use:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader{\bfseries \dotfill}}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works quite nicely. (I think you meant to insert a closing brace after `cftchapleader' in the last renewcommand.)

Comment: @mlchristians: Indeed, thanks!